# Spring MVC. HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-tool-suite

I created maven project "File->New->Other..->Maven->Maven Project"
I created controller + view, "Hello World" and everything worked well.
I foolishly decided to click RightClick(on project)->Maven->Update Project (tomcat was running).
On the project appeared "red exclamation" and "HelloWorld" doesnt work.

[image]

Screen after "my updating"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mdosoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>Primer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Primer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Primer</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: make sure the Spring jars are actually present in WEB-INF of your application in Tomcat.

Comment: clean install - no change (

Comment: Stop tomcat, clean project, maven->updateProject, deploy(build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **mvn clean package** ensure that all the jars are inside of lib folder. If it doesn't work change servlet api version to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide pom.xml file,
Check The Scope Of `servlet api-3.0.1` depaendency,it must be `provided`

Comment: make sure All `jar` files are available, otherwise include dependency for all.